# Orchard module gallery reports error

Tags: c#, module, gallery, orchardcms

I've installed a few instances of OrchardProject.net and all of them are reporting an error when trying to browse the module gallery.

Error loading extensions from gallery source 'Orchard Extensions Gallery'. The null value from property 'Published' cannot be assigned to a type 'System.DateTime'..

Steps to reproduce:
1.  Go to admin
2.  Click on gallery / module
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be fixed now. We are currently updating a bunch of things, preparing for the launch of 1.1. Sorry for the interruption.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I fixed it by granting write permission to the Modules folder to the IIS_IUSRS group in my case as I am running IIS 7.

I had to apply the same permission to the Themes folder as well before I could install extra themes.